# What is $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) /SL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all real n by n matrices whose determinant is 1.
$GL_N(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all real n by n matrices whose determinant is non-zero.
I have proved that $SL_n$ is normal in $GL_n$.

Then What is $GL_N(\mathbb{R})/SL_n(\mathbb{R})$? I mean, can we find another expression for $GL_n /SL_n=\{ASL_n \mid A \in GL_n \}$? My guess is it's the set of all real n by n matrices whose determinant is not 1.

is my guess correct? or what should it be?

Comment: General tip for such things:  find an obvious homomorphism $\phi: GL_n \to X$ for an obvious group $X$ whose kernel is $SL_n$.

Comment: @Randall Take $\phi = det$ and $X=\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ then the $ker(\phi)=SL_n$, so by the 1st isomorphism theorem, we have $GL_n / SL_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$. but how does this help us to prove $GL_n/ SL_n$=the set of all real n by n matrices whose determinant is not 1 ?

Comment: Because that's false.  The set of matrices with $\det \neq 1$ is not even a goup:  what will be the identity?  Plus, multiplication isn't even close to being a closed operation on this set.  The argument you give in your comment is actually the right argument to prove that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\times$.

Comment: @Randall. Ok.. but my question is what is $GL_n / SL_n$ ? it got to be some set of something right? can the fact that this quotient is isomorphic to $R^{times}$ help us to find $GL_n / SL_n$?

Comment: It is what it is.  It is a group of cosets, period.  The elements are cosets $ASL_n$ where $A \in GL_n$.  This representation is not unique in $A$, so we try to identify it up to iso to make life easier.  In this case, it is iso to the multiplicative group of nonzero reals.

Comment: @Randall yeah..i know the definition of a quotient group. but what i mean is , can we simplify the expression $GL_n/SL_n=\{ASL_n \mid A \in GL_n \}$ if we know $SL_n$ is normal in $GL_n$?

Comment: No, that's the whole problem.  That's why it's handy to know what it is iso to in simpler terms.  You can choose a convenient representative for each coset by selecting a single nice matrix of determinant $x$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^\times$, something like $x$ in position $(1,1)$, 1's on the rest of the diagonal, and zeros elsewhere.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Randall The original question is: Prove $SL_n$ is normal in $GL_n$ and what is $GL_n / SL_n$?  i have proved that $SL_n$ is normal, but i do not think my prof is asking about the definition of $GL_n /SL_n$, i guess what he wants is start with the definition, then proceed using the information $SL_n$ is normal, to see of what form would the quotient group be.

Comment: "What is" is pretty vague.  Mostly in algebra this is code for "identify it up to iso as something nicer" which is why you were getting these answers.  I would ask the prof what he's fishing for.